# Symfony SymfMail - how to send an email

Tags: php, symfony, email

I want to send an email with symfony symfmail but theres a problem. My code doesn't throw error but it isn't sending anything. What's worse, it doesn't show is my connection with smtp correct or any error. What to do?

Here's my controller method:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/mail")
 */
public function mail(\Swift_Mailer $mailer){
    $message = (new Swift_Message('Wonderful Subject'))
        ->setFrom(['I SET IT!' => 'John Doe'])
        ->setTo(['I SET IT!', 'I SET IT!' => 'A name'])
        ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
    ;

    $result = $mailer->send($message);
    return new Response(var_dump($result));
}
```

I don't know. Maybe i just doesn't configure it good or smtp is not configured form my wamp64 in localhost.

Please help with that.

UPDATE:

I get this code when i look into toolbar errors. Is it because i send it form localhost?

```
Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host localhost [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. #10061]
```

my .env file

```
    # This file is a "template" of which env vars need to be defined for your application
# Copy this file to .env file for development, create environment variables when deploying to production
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#infrastructure-related-configuration

###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=e772aaf55e2eb077062f1d98468e6f59
#TRUSTED_PROXIES=127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
#TRUSTED_HOSTS=localhost,example.com
###< symfony/framework-bundle ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# For an SQLite database, use: "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# Configure your db driver and server_version in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/cms
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###
# For Gmail as a transport, use: "gmail://username:password@localhost"
# For a generic SMTP server, use: "smtp://localhost:25?encryption=&auth_mode="
# Delivery is disabled by default via "null://localhost"
MAILER_URL=smtp://MY_MAIL_WITHOUT_AT_CHAR_AND_DOMAIN:MY_PASSWORD@EMAILDOMAIN:SSL_PORT
#MAILER_URL=smtp://localhost:25?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=&password=
#MAILER_URL=null://localhost
###< symfony/swiftmailer-bundle ###
```

UPDATE: Ok i know where's problem i tried send it from console and this is what i got:

```
19:40:53 ERROR     [app] Exception occurred while flushing email queue: 
Connection could not be established with host localhost [No connection could be made because the target machin
e actively refused it.
 #10061]
```

Comment: I assume `I SET IT!` is you redacting a valid email address, and not how your code actually looks?

Comment: There is a lot of reasons that can make such a problem. But before everything please read this guide: https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html
I think you forgot to configure your environment related variables. Also, you can check your problem by Symfony Profiler. use this document: https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/dev_environment.html#viewing-from-the-web-debug-toolbar

Comment: @zack6849 yes, i don't want recive spam so i put this text there.

Comment: @HamidYousefi: ok toolbar works im looking for an error

Comment: @HamidYousefi:  see on my edited post

Comment: @hjhfkasdjhfhuiw well, at least you find your problem. can you please give me more information about your config files. if you set ENV inside the apache or nginx configuration give me them or if you using `.env` file, just paste them here

Comment: Please update your question with your `.env` file, so I can see what server you try to connect.

Comment: @HamidYousefi i did, see now

Comment: @HamidYousefi i updated post. This is problem with localhost

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your `.env` configuration!

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://MY_MAIL_WITHOUT_AT_CHAR_AND_DOMAIN:MY_PASSWORD@EMAILDOMAIN:SSL_PORT
```

please change it and give your Email Credentials and Configurations so you can send emails with it.

I am not a Windows user, but based on your environment, if you have any mail server, it is configured on your localhost, like your web server. so just find the port its listening.

Comment: Thanks, its stupid question but how to see is i have mail server?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do it yet but i see it's problem with sending emails from localhost, because even with mail() function it didn't work but on my server in web it did. Thanks for help.